# Xcode completion menu not completing on enter, I have to use mouse/touchpad cursor and click there...

Tags: macos, keyboard, xcode

Xcode completion menu not completing on enter, I have to use mouse/touchpad cursor and click there, so its quite annoying. How can I just autocomplete by keyboard ? Is this some miss-configuration of keybindings ? I never used Xcode editor so I am not sure if this is not standard behavior... Coming from App-code so I am used to do everything by keyboard but most of keybindings I had to re-configure...

Comment: No special configuration is required for autocompletion to work using keyboard. Kindly [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/344014/edit) the question and specify the exactly how you are expecting the autocomplete to work, what keys are you using etc.

Comment: Do you mean that the autocompletion context menu doesn't *open* without hovering/clicking with the mouse cursor or actually *selecting* an entry from it won't work by pressing enter?

Comment: @Gero selecting by pressing enter is not working, I have to click there and select by cursor, I want to choose the completion by up/down keys and press enter but enter just will make new line in editor...

Answer (score 1):

This is weird and seems to be a bug in your installation somehow, i.e. it's certainly not how Xcode is supposed to work.

The standard shortcut to *open* the code completion menu (which seems to work for you, I'm just being thorough here) is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. For some reason simply pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> also works (at least for me, has always been that way and I always used the default settings in Xcode).

*Stepping through* the suggestions has, according to the settings, the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (that's a full stop) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, but using the arrow keys also works for me (and always has), in spite of not being defined in the settings.

*Selecting/confirming* an entry doesn't even have a shortcut per se, because it's less an Xcode and more of a standard selection mechanism for any similar kind of list under macOS I guess. It doesn't even show up in the settings as far as I can see it. For me (and everybody else I have ever worked with) it's done as you expect as well: Pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> (both work).

This unfortunately only answers half of your question: As said, the behavior you see is not the standard (or to be expected at all).

I'd suggest to take a look at the "Key Bindings" section of the Preferences ("Xcode - Preferences..." menu), though I assume you already did that. It can list conflicts for you. Other than that you also might want to take a look at the general input settings (" - System Preferences... - Keyboard"). You can also define various keyboard shortcuts there, maybe that's causing some kind of conflict.

Comment: Looks like reinstall of xCode then is waiting for me... I checked again conflicts and disabled all system key shortcuts because I don't use them, but Enter just makes new line when I have open competition menu and selected item there :), good to know it's not standard behavior, I can hope for better in near future.

Comment: After reinstallation of my whole system it started to work as intended :)

Comment: Oh dear, I'm sorry you had to go through a complete reinstallation! :( Let's hope this was a one-time oddity. Have fun coding away now!

Comment: Well not really I had issue on my ssd where only option was to reformat so thats why I ended like this... anyway as a side effect, enter works for Xcode completion now ...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, turns out I somehow messed with my key bindings.

To fix this, I removed the following entry from `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings/Default.idekeybindings`, and then restarted Xcode:

```
-           <key>
-</key>
-           <string>insertNewline:</string>
```